# Algorithm to find keywords of a text

Tags: algorithm

Given a set of texts (might be books, articles, documents, etc.) how would you find relevant keywords for each text?
Common sense suggests to:

- split words
- exclude common words (also called stop-words, like "a,
  to, for, in")
- count words frequencies
- give a score to each word, with a formula that takes into account the frequency of each word in the document and in other documents, the number of words of the document and the total number of words of all documents

The question is: which is a good formula to do that?

Answer (score 7):

I've developed one.

For each word calculate this ratio:

```
(frequency of word in this text) * (total number of words in all texts)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (number of words in this text) * (frequency of word in all texts)
```

Keywords are those words whose ratio is in the highest 20% (for this doucument).

[Ankerl](http://martin.ankerl.com/2007/01/09/textanalyzer-automatically-extract-characteristic-words/) also proposes his own formula:

```
tanh(curVal/curWords*200) - 5*tanh((allVal-curVal)/(allWords-curWords)*200)
```

Where:

- curVal: How often the word to score is present in the to-be-analyzed text
- curWords: Total number of words in the to-be-analyzed text
- allVal: How often the word to score is present in the indexed dataset
- allWords: Total number of words of the indexed dataset

Both algorithms work pretty well, and results often coincide. Do you know any way to do it better?

Comment: Have you got access to layout info (titles, breaks , font size and styles ...) ?